# Finding the element with the largest even digit across multiple arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am having problems finding the element with the greatest even digit
in a set of arrays. The code I have written only takes positive numbers into
consideration. All the negative values are completely ignored.

```
int main() {

 int ary1[] = { 123, 456, -7890, 12 };
 int ary2[] = {-123, 654, 78, 15, 189};
 int ary3[] = {9, 9};
 int ary4[] = {123, 123, 0, 12};
 int ary5[] = {24, 45, -789, 24, 1};
 int ary6[] = {-749, -241, 1, 45};
 int ary7[] = {1, 3, 5};

 digitExtract(ary1, 4);
}

void digitExtract(int Array[], int array_size) {

 int max = Array[0];

 for (int i = 1; i < array_size; i++)
 {
  if (Array[i] > max)
   max = Array[i];
 }

 printf("\nThe largest element is: %d\n", max);
}
```

I have a basic idea, which is to loop through each element
and turn it into a positive number ( get absolute value in order for it to be processed ), but I am not sure how
to implement the code.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: So what's the problem?  Are you getting compile errors?  Wrong answer?

Comment: The problem is in my initial post. The function won't process the negative values stored in the arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by "largest even digit"? Perhaps a few examples would help. As it is, your code correctly finds the element with the highest numeric value. But it's not clear what you want it to do instead.

Comment: What do you mean "won't process negative values"? It certainly does process the negative value in your example. It may not do it the way you think it should but it certainly does not ignore it like you are claiming. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confuse... You also mention a set of arrays and you have only one array...

Comment: Why you think the negative value is not taking in consideration?  Your code is looking for the greatest value in the array.  Your negative value is lesser than all the other values and that is correct.

Comment: We are looking for the value with the highest even digit, not just the larger element in terms of value. So for example between 1006 and -1008, we would pick -1008 because it has 8, the highest even digit.

Comment: No where in your code do you check for even numbers/digits. So regardless of negative or not the code can not be doing that part correctly. For the negative part just use `abs` to get the absolute value. Not sure there's much to say beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should do what you are looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void digitExtract(int Array[], int array_size);

int main() {
    int ary1[] = { 123, 456, -7890, 12 };
    int ary2[] = { -123, 654, 78, 15, 189 };
    int ary3[] = { 9, 9 };
    int ary4[] = { 123, 123, 0, 12 };
    int ary5[] = { 24, 45, -789, 24, 1 };
    int ary6[] = { -749, -241, 1, 45 };
    int ary7[] = { 1, 3, 5 };

    digitExtract(ary1, 4);
    digitExtract(ary2, 5);
    digitExtract(ary3, 2);
    digitExtract(ary4, 4);
    digitExtract(ary5, 5);
    digitExtract(ary6, 4);
    digitExtract(ary7, 3);
}

void digitExtract(int Array[], int array_size) {

    int maxDigitNumber;
    int maxDigitFound = -1;
    int tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        tmp = Array[i] < 0 ? -Array[i]: Array[i];

        do {
            if (tmp % 2 == 0 && maxDigitFound < (tmp % 10)) {
                maxDigitFound = tmp % 10;
                maxDigitNumber = Array[i];
            }    

            tmp /= 10;
        } while (tmp > 0)
    }

    if (maxDigitFound > -1)
        printf("\nThe largest digit is: %d and the element is: %d\n", maxDigitFound, maxDigitNumber);
    else
        printf("\nThere is not an even number in the array\n");
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Note: By using a `do { ... } while (tmp > 0)`, code will not fail  the corner case of `int ary[] = { 0, 0, 0, ... };`

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking for how to convert all the values in an integer array to positive values, you can just do that with a loop:

```
void digitExtract(int Array[], int array_size) {

  for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    Array[i] = abs(Array[i]);

  int max = Array[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < array_size; i++)
  {
    if (Array[i] > max)
      max = Array[i];
  }

  printf("\nThe largest element is: %d\n", max);


}
```

In reality, you don't need to do this, since you can compare the absolute values instead of converting everything to positives before comparison. This works too:

```
void digitExtract(int Array[], int array_size) {

   int max = abs(Array[0]);

   for (int i = 1; i < array_size; i++)
   {
     if (abs(Array[i]) > max)
     max = Array[i];
   }

 printf("\nThe largest element is: %d\n", max);


}
```

Either way, you're going to need

```
#include <stdlib.h>`
```

where abs(int n) is.

Absolute Value: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/

Comment: Note: `int max = abs(Array[0]);` likely fails to provide a positive answer for `INT_MIN`.

Comment: Admittedly, I was operating on the assumption that that would not be an issue based on the problem statement

Answer (score -1):

This may help ...
I'm using ASCII values of the digits 0-9 to compare.
ASCII values of digits 0 to 9 are from 48 to 57.
First convert each number e.g. 456 to a string i.e. "456".
Then consider it 1 character at a time i.e. '4', then '5', then '6'.
So we compare ASCII value of '4' to that of '5'.
We check to ensure that the ASCII value is an 'even' number.
If it is even we consider it for comparison, else we do not.

What should happen if 2 elements have the same even digit e.g. -749 & -241 ? They both have 4.
What should happen to arrays that only have odd numbers e.g. ary3[ ] & ary7[ ] ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myFunc(int [], int);


int main()
{
        int ary1[] = { 123, 456, -7890, 12 };
        int ary2[] = { -123, 654, 78, 15, 189 };
        int ary3[] = { 9, 9 };
        int ary4[] = { 123, 123, 0, 12 };
        int ary5[] = { 24, 45, -789, 24, 1 };
        int ary6[] = { -749, -241, 1, 45 };
        int ary7[] = { 1, 3, 5 };

        myFunc(ary1, 4);
        myFunc(ary2, 5);
        myFunc(ary3, 2);
        myFunc(ary4, 4);
        myFunc(ary5, 5);
        myFunc(ary6, 4);
        myFunc(ary7, 3);

        return 0;
}

void myFunc(int Array[], int size)
{
        int iLen = 0, myIndx = 0;
        int iMax = 0, iOverallMax = 0;
        char myArray[50] = "";

        int i, j = 0;
        for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
                sprintf(myArray, "%d", abs(Array[i])); // Convert int to string.
                iLen = strlen(myArray); // Get length e.g. len of "456" = 3

                if((myArray[j] % 2) == 0)  // We are only interested in even digits ...
                        iMax = myArray[j]; // Set iMax = ASCII value of myArray[0] i.e. ASCII value of '4'
                else
                        iMax = 0;
                j++;
                while(j < iLen) // Have to loop through digits in "456".
                {
                        // We are only interested in even digits per element ...
                        if((myArray[j] > iMax) && ((myArray[j] % 2) == 0))
                                iMax = myArray[j]; // Assigns ASCII value of myArray[j] e.g. '6' to iMax.
                        j++;
                }

                // Save the Array Index of the element with the max even digit found so far.
                if(iMax > iOverallMax)
                {
                        iOverallMax = iMax; // Save the ASCII value of the max even digit so far.
                        myIndx = i; // Save the Array Index.
                }

                // Reset variables ... and repeat the process for the next element in the Array.
                j = 0;
                strcpy(myArray, "");
        }

        printf("\nThe Array element with the largest even digit is: %d\n", Array[myIndx]);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want the element with the largest even 'digit', regardless of whether the 'element' is odd or even e.g. for ary[] = {-789, 242}, answer is -789 since it has the largest even digit i.e. 8 ...

Comment: Would have appreciated a comment as to why there is a -1 against this answer ... i (and others) can learn, if there is a legitimate issue ...